# Where's the file-picker dialog in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

<del>http://i.minus.com/i3xuoWZkpfxHn.png</del>

I don't see anything that would let me pick files from my computer... there has to be one, where is it? I'm probably missing a reference?

---

**Edit:** What I had in mind was a textbox with a "Browse" button beside it. It occurs to me now that I probably have to place the textbox and browse button myself and add a click event to the button to open the dialog...

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Yeah...sure is. Sorry. Can't find it in any archives.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There is no built-in control that has a textbox with a [Browse] button beside it. You gotta set that up yourself.

For the "open file" dialog itself, there is the [`OpenFileDialog` in Microsoft.Win32 namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx#Common_Dialogs).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does the OpenFileDialog in the Microsoft.Win32 namespace differ from the one in the System.Windows.Forms namespace?

Comment: @MattBridges I believe it's basically the WPF version of the WinForms dialog that doesn't require referencing System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Answer (score 31):

For a more feature complete answer, assume you have a Button `BtnFileOpen` and a textbox `TxtFile`. First you need to reference the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly from the references dialog (make sure you check mark it, double clicking it didn't seem to add it for me).

Inside the button click event:

```
private void BtnFileOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    var result = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
    switch (result)
    {
        case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK:
            var file = fileDialog.FileName;
            TxtFile.Text = file;
            TxtFile.ToolTip = file;
            break;
        case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel:
        default:
            TxtFile.Text = null;
            TxtFile.ToolTip = null;
            break;
    }
}
```

If you have set your textbox to disabled you may wish to edit your xaml to include

`ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"`

Answer (score 5):

I generally just use the `OpenFileDialog` in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. I alias it using `SWF`, and then it just becomes

```
SWF.OpenFileDialog o = new SWF.OpenFileDialog();
```

Comment: And if you want to use a filepicker for a save-file picker prompt, just change `OpenFileDialog` to `SaveFileDialog`

Comment: What's the benefit of using `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` instead of `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`?